# Xcode does not recognize TIFF functions

Tags: c, xcode, compiler-errors, libtiff

I have been trying to run a code that uses tiffutils to handle TIFF images. I am encountering the good old "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64, that has already come up multiple times here. However, none of the threads were helpful in solving my issue. The errors are described as follows:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_TIFFClose", referenced from:
      _GetImageFromTiff in tiffutils.o
      _WriteImageToTiff in tiffutils.o
  "_TIFFGetField", referenced from:
      _GetImageFromTiff in tiffutils.o
  "_TIFFOpen", referenced from:
      _GetImageFromTiff in tiffutils.o
      _WriteImageToTiff in tiffutils.o
  "_TIFFReadScanline", referenced from:
      _GetImageFromTiff in tiffutils.o
  "_TIFFScanlineSize", referenced from:
      _GetImageFromTiff in tiffutils.o
  "_TIFFSetField", referenced from:
      _WriteImageToTiff in tiffutils.o
  "_TIFFWriteScanline", referenced from:
      _WriteImageToTiff in tiffutils.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

After many attempts and wondering on the internet seeking a solution, I realized that the problem must be that Xcode is unable to detect the tiff library. The compiler seems to complain about not recognizing some very core functions in the tiff library. I don't understand how it is possible though, since I did make sure it was installed and that I include the libtiff library on Xcode's Build Setting.

I don't know what else to do so I was hoping you guys could help me out here. Any suggestions?

**More information that may be helpful (not sure if I need it all, this project was written ages ago on Linux, and I am trying to compile it on Mac OS):

(1) My libtiff library is located under: usr/local/libtiff-4.0.6
(2) I added it going to my target then Build Setting --> Library Search Paths, then clicked on the right column and added the library usr/local/libtiff-4.0.6 to it.
(3) My project Makefile looks like this:

```
# Makefile for creating shape-texture spaces

TIFFUTILS_DIR = ../../tiffutils

CC =        gcc

CPPFLAGS=   -O3 -m32 -I$(TIFFUTILS_DIR) -I/usr/include -Wall

LDFLAGS =   -m32 -L$(TIFFUTILS_DIR)/bin -L/usr/lib
LOADLIBES =     -ltiffutils -ltiff

vpath %.c ..

SRC2_C =    bimgalloc.c bimgio.c btof.c btol.c btos.c canny2.c \
       die.c fileutils.c filtsub.c fimgalloc.c fimgio.c freflect.c \
       ftob.c ftol.c ftos.c imgalloc.c limgalloc.c limgio.c ltob.c \
       ltof.c ltos.c nint.c simgalloc.c simgio.c stob.c stof.c stol.c \
       timgio.c

SRC2_O =    $(SRC2_C:.c=.o)

canny2: $(SRC2_O)

SRC_C = bimgalloc.c bimgio.c btof.c btol.c btos.c canny.c \
       die.c fileutils.c filtsub.c fimgalloc.c fimgio.c freflect.c \
       ftob.c ftol.c ftos.c imgalloc.c limgalloc.c limgio.c ltob.c \
       ltof.c ltos.c nint.c simgalloc.c simgio.c stob.c stof.c stol.c \
       timgio.c

SRC_O = $(SRC_C:.c=.o)

canny: $(SRC_O)

clean:
    rm *.o canny canny2

#
# EOF
#
```

(4) I also have a tiffutils Makefile that looks like this:

```
LIB =       libtiffutils.a

CC =        gcc
ARFLAGS =   ursv
CPPFLAGS=   -I.. -Wall -O3 -m32

vpath %.c ..

LIB_TIFFUTILS_C = tiffutils.c
LIB_TIFFUTILS_O = $(LIB_TIFFUTILS_C:.c=.o)

all: libtiffutils

libtiffutils: $(LIB_TIFFUTILS_O)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $(LIB) $(LIB_TIFFUTILS_O)


clean:
    rm $(LIB) $(LIB_TIFFUTILS_O)
```

Thank you for reading this!

Comment: please post details about where the tiff library is installed and exactly how you told xcode to find that library.  you might post the automatically generated makefile

Comment: @user3629249 added, thanks!

Comment: there seems to be a discrepancy between the relative path: `TIFFUTILS_DIR = ../../tiffutils`  and where you state the library is actually located: ` usr/local/libtiff-4.0.6`  the make operation will fail unless it is run from one directory over and 2 directories down from where the the library is located.   Have you examined that directory /usr/local/libtiff-4.0.6//tiffutils to see if the archive file `libtiffutils.a` (or maybe `libtiffutils.so` is actually in existence?

Comment: why would your project be located in /usr/local/  rather than in /home/$(login)/project?  (or some very similar directory under /home/?)  In general, library paths should be starting at `/` not relative to where your project is located.

Comment: @user3629249 I have checked and I do have the right path which directs to libtiffutils.a. When I check all the library paths I have included in the Xcode GUI, nothing is missing to operate. All the required files are there. Maybe Xcode does not read my Makefile? or the tiffutils Makefile? Is this possible? Basically what I did was to add the project's Makefile to the source code list (but unchecked the target membership box), assuming that xCode will know to run it if it is there. Plus, I referred it to the tiffutils Makefile on the library search paths. Will Xcode know to read it?

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, go to project setting, General tab. Under Embedded binaries session, add your library. Hope that help

Comment: Thanks for your reply @sahara108. As I mentioned, I am trying to compile for a Mac OS X operating system. The Embedded binaries are for IOS applications. Perhaps the equivalent is to add the library to "Library Search Path" under Build Setting, which I already tried..

Answer (score 0):

where is your project located on your computer?

I expect it to be located at:

```
/home/<username>/<projectname>
```

and you have stated that the tiffutils is located at:

```
/usr/local/libtiff-4.0.6/tiffutils
```

The relative path in the makefile says (BTW: why a relative path?)

(breaking it down step by step.)

```
/home/<username> leaves ../tiffutils/libtiffutils.

/home/tiffutils/libtiffutils.
```

That is absolutely not the same as:

```
/usr/local/libtiff-4.0.6/tiffutils/libtiffutils.
```

So the path to the library needs to be an absolute path that looks like:

```
/usr/local/libtiff-4.0.6/tiffutils
```

Comment: Ok I understand.. Although it seems like nothing that I change on the makefile matters. It is as if Xcode doesn't read the makefile at all.. This is why I ask if there is a specific way to tell Xcode that there is an existing Makefile to read, or do I just add it to the list of sources?